# How to sum values from Java Hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I need some help, I'm learning by myself how to deal with maps in Java ando today i was trying to get the sum of the values from a Hashmap but now Im stuck.

This are the map values that I want to sum.

```
HashMap<String, Float> map = new HashMap<String, Float>();

map.put("First Val", (float) 33.0);
map.put("Second Val", (float) 24.0);
```

Ass an additional question, what if I have 10 or 20 values in a map, how can I sum all of them, do I need to make a "for"?

Regards and thanks for the help.

Comment: Insteaf of `(float) 33.0` you can use `33f` or `33.0f`

Comment: What steps would *you* do to sum a bunch of values from a collection of unknown size? Yes, a "for" or a "loop" sounds appropriate - search for it.

Comment: I do not think this question is a real duplicate. This is more specific. and the solution in java 8 is map.values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to add *all* the values in a `Map`, try this:

```
float sum = 0.0f;
for (float f : map.values()) {
    sum += f;
}
```

At the end, the `sum` variable will contain the answer. So yes, for traversing a `Map`'s values it's best to use a `for` loop.

Comment: you beat me to it! +1

Comment: Thank's a lot for your time, it works and i have the result that i wanted!!

Comment: In java 8 you can do
        map.values().stream().sum()

Answer (score 4):

```
Float sum = 0f;
for (Float val : map.values()){
    sum += val;
}

//sum now contains the sum!
```

A `for` loop indeed serves well for the intended purpose, although you could also use a while loop and an iterator...

Comment: Thank's a lot for your time!

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely do that using a `for-loop`. You can either use an entry set:

```
for (Entry<String, Float> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    sum += entry.getValue();
}
```

or in this case just:

```
for (float value : map.values()) {
    sum += value;
}
```