# Create Method to sum up all Values in a HashMap for Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to add up all the values for any Hashmap. The hash map will have two Integers. First as a key and the second as a value. I am getting errors in the compiler as I am not sure how to do this. I want to return the total value of all the values in the `hash` map.

I would like this method to work for any `hash` map that I place into this method's parameter and return

I am a 7th grader trying to learn java on my own at the moment. If someone can show me how to also run this in a main method with a passed in hash map that would be super.

I am getting these `errors`:
Multiple markers at this line
    - value cannot be resolved to a type
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Integer to value
    - Line breakpoint:PopulationTotal [line: 10] - getTotal(HashMap)
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier" to complete 
     EnhancedForStatementHeaderInit

I am trying this:

```
public int getTotal (HashMap<Integer, Integer> p) {
    for (value : p.values()) {
        int total += value;
    }
    return total
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum values from Java Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665538/how-to-sum-values-from-java-hashmap)

Comment: You need to declare `total` before the loop, not inside it.

Comment: Just declare `total` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Side note: use interfaces not implementation classes as method parameters, wherever possible (Map instead of HashMap).

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare type of the for-each variable.
Also, initialize total as 0 outside the loop. 
Try this:

```
public int getTotal (HashMap<Integer, Integer> p) {
int total = 0;
for (int value : p.values()) {
    total += value;
}
return total
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or shorter this way :

```
public int getTotal (HashMap<Integer, Integer> p) {
    return p.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
}
```

Thank's to Stream API, JAVA 8 provides functional programming capabilities.
But the paradigm is a little bit different from classical programming